# Titanium filesystem : How to Error Logging

Tags: javascript, titanium-sdk

I'm trying that when the invalid api key message appears in my prueba.js file, the application shows the log out message but it doesn't. I am also printing the api key message via a console.log

Titanium version 12.1.2.GA

```
// Importar el módulo FileSystem de Titanium
var FileSystem = require('Ti.Filesystem');

// Ruta del archivo prueba.js
var filePath = 'prueba.js';

// Leer el contenido del archivo prueba.js
var file = FileSystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, filePath);
var contents = file.read().text;

// Buscar el error "API KEY INVALID AUTH" en el contenido
if (contents.includes("API KEY INVALID AUTH")) {
  // Realizar el log out del usuario
  logout();
} else {
  // Continuar con la lógica normal de la aplicación
  console.log("El contenido de prueba.js no contiene el error 'API KEY INVALID AUTH'.");
}

// Función para realizar el log out del usuario
function logout() {
  // Aquí puedes agregar el código necesario para cerrar la sesión del usuario
  // Por ejemplo, puedes borrar las credenciales de autenticación almacenadas o redirigir al usuario a la pantalla de inicio de sesión
  console.log("Se ha realizado el log out del usuario.");
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here. You don't need to require Ti.Filesystem like this, you can just use it. See https://titaniumsdk.com/api/titanium/filesystem/file.html#reading-a-file . Try to log `contents` to see if it has content or even try `file.exists()` before to see if the file is available. Keep in mind `The Resources directory and all the files in it are read-only` so the value of your file doesn't change so you should know if it contains your API key or not when you build your project.